# Updating Gems for Older Versions of Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I used Ruby `2.2.0` earlier and so many of my gems are in

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
```

Now I am using Ruby `2.3.0`, and so my `GEM_PATH` no longer contains the path to those gems, but only

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
```

So I cannot use those `2.2.0` gems anymore. How can I migrate those gems into this new `2.3.0` folder?

----UPDATE----

I am trying to use RVM, but it changes the installation path of the gems to

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
```

Then how can I migrate the gems in the original paths to this new one?

Comment: Are you using either `rbenv` or `rvm` to manage your Ruby versions?

Comment: @Drenmi check the path to gemsets: 99% no manager is used.

Comment: @Drenmi No I'm not using any manager. How I can accomplish this with a manager?

Comment: @0472037 http://rvm.io/

Comment: Use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) for managing ruby versions and gems and for installing on ubuntu  [follow steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @unkmas Should I use `rvm upgrade 2.2.0 2.3.0` to migrate the gems? When I execute this command it complains `The source ruby was not a valid ruby string.`

Comment: using of rvm is general hint. Now you can just cp old gems to new path. But why are you care about old gems? Why don't just reinstall them?